# Laravel 5.2 made project not working on production server

Tags: laravel-5

I've made a project with laravel 5.2 and when I upload on production server it does not works and nothing, of course I upload on a **sub domain**. It works on my computer fine but if I move it to another computer it does not, except I change **debug option** in **.env** file to false and comment **xdebu** of line in **php.ini.**
Don't know how to make it to work on production server

Any help

Comment: sure about config parameters? what's the error, kindly attach the screenshot or error description

Comment: This is link of question I asked yesterday [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/blade-view-are-not-showing)